# How can we Acquire k-line data for all market from Coinex?

Tags: python, candlestick-chart

I plan to acquire all market candles from the exchange every 5 minutes. Coinex exchange has provided the following API for this task, but this API returns only one candle of a market each time. When I start receiving each of the symbols, the server detects the program as malware due to the high volume of requests and blocks the download.
https://api.coinex.com/v1/market/kline?market=BCHBTC&type=5min

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

i suggest you use websocket connection to receive information you need, sending HTTP request have limits, its different on every exchange based on their infrastructure, they block the request you send for a limited time.
so use websocket connection if all you have to do is getting information.

check this out for more information:
https://github.com/coinexcom/coinex_exchange_api/wiki

Comment: I've used ccxt library, and it has some method to fetch candles, every time you can fetch one symbol of the market, it has a rate limit used to limit fetching data. Rate limit causes delays in the receipt of data. Do you @sep any idea to improve the solution

Answer (score -1):

You should to set "limit":

https://api.coinex.com/perpetual/v1/market/kline?market=ETHUSDT&type=1day
&limit=50

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).